# Change countries during 30% ruling

Tags: netherlands, tax-deductions

I moved to Netherlands 2.5 years ago and and have 30% ruling. Now I want to move to my girlfriend home in Belgium but still continue to work in the Netherlands. In this conditions do I still have access to the 30% ruling for the rest of the 5 years?

Comment: Tough one, I don't really know but I don't see any explicit requirement that would bar you from continuing to benefit from it. Have you looked into other implications of this move? Situations like that can have numerous consequences for taxes and health insurance. For example, it seems you will have to [file a tax return in Belgium](https://www.svb.nl/en/bbz-bdz/leaflets/cross-border-commuters-belgium) as well and might need to pay some local taxes based on your income (before or after the 30% discount, I don't know…).

Comment: Related: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13376/does-remote-work-from-the-netherlands-get-30-ruling?rq=1